# find the average store size of a document type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I know the size (in bytes) that a specific document type takes (say, type 1 and type2)?

If I try:

```
curl -XGET 
'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_stats?clear=true&store=true&indexing=true&types=type1,type2'
```

I only get the total size in bytes of the index.

I am actually interested in the average size of a document of a certain type, but this can be deduced from the count and the total size I guess

Comment: Guess you get the answer already, but if anyone stumble on this post again, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28335626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different types are indexed using the same index and share many common structures. So, it's not really possible to tell how much one type is taking without considering the effect of another type.

Comment: Thanks, how about the store size? without the indexes?

Comment: It would be hard to keep track of it. Consider deleting by query for example.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer says, there's not a way to do this built into elasticsearch.

not sure if this is obvious or not, butttttt I needed to accomplish the same thing to track some out of control index growth, so I added an optional debug index where the app that acts as my central point for indexing actually logs the size of each document, its id after indexing, and some other pertinent info to help me track down what the docs were that were taking up all that space.

this approach isn't 100% accurate since biggest before compression doesn't necessarily indicate biggest after compression (pretty sure ES compresses docs and i think stores them in a binary json format?), but it definitely pointed me in the right direction.