# Elasticsearch, get average document length

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any better way in elasticsearch (other than issuing a match all query and manually averaging over the length of all returned documents) to get the average document length for a specific index?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [_size mapping field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-size-field.html), if enabled, should give you the size of each document for free.  Combining this with the `avg` aggregation should get you what you want.  Something like:

```
{
  "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
  "aggs" : {"avg_size" : {"avg" : {"terms" : {"field" : "_size"}}}}
}
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer :)

Comment: If you want to get size of documents you need to instruct ES to store size for each document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-size-field.html

Comment: Unless you're using Elasticsearch 2.0 or older, this feature is no more supported.

Comment: On recent versions of `elasticsearch` you need install plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size.html (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/804)

Answer (score 3):

I have used this code (I have the _source enabled)

```
{
  "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
  "aggs":{
    "avg_length" : { "avg" : { "script" : "_source.toString().length()"}}
  }
}
```

Well, the chars .. .if the string are UTF-8 to get the bytes:

```
{
  "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
  "aggs":{
    "avg_length" : { "avg" : { "script" : "_source.toString().getBytes(\"UTF-8\").length"}}
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it has been working only with `groovy` scripting language which is absent now by default. In painless on `params._source.toString()` you just got something like `org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.SourceLookup@72e72146`

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but facets or aggregations combined with a script might do it.

```
{
    ...,

    "aggs" : {
        "avg_length" : { "avg" : { "script" : "doc['_all'].length" } }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually fails with +org.elasticsearch.index.search.nested.NonNestedDocsFilter@62d17f59))],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[Exception evaluating property 'length' for org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: length for class: java.lang.String]]; "

Comment: try  doc['_all'].values.size() instead

Comment: First of all, the _all field is not always present, as it depends on the index template.
Secondly, in this way you're getting the `The _all field is a special catch-all field which concatenates the values of all of the other fields into one big string, using space as a delimiter, [...]` as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html and it is deprecated in 6.x

Answer (score 1):

In ElasticSearch 6.2 you should just use the following line (no need to add 'terms'):

```
  "aggs" : 
      {"avg_size" : 
           {"avg" : 
               {"field" : "_size"}}}
```

See details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html