# Is it possible to get the total size in bytes of all documents in an Elasticsearch type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't submit this question with just a title. Is it possible to get the total size in bytes of all documents in an Elasticsearch type?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141670/find-the-average-store-size-of-a-document-type-in-elasticsearch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335340/elasticsearch-get-average-document-length